# Can't read the arguments on a second screen using PushNamed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following code that is passing an object as an Argument to another screen using Push named:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_nsd/flutter_nsd.dart';
import 'package:australremote/screens/screen5.dart';
import 'package:australremote/screens/screen6.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Screen1());
}

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  final flutterNsd = FlutterNsd();
  final services = <NsdServiceInfo>[];
  bool initialStart = true;
  bool _scanning = false;
  //List<String> _deviceIPAddresses = [];



  _Screen1State();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Try one restart if initial start fails, which happens on hot-restart of
    // the flutter app.
    flutterNsd.stream.listen(
          (NsdServiceInfo service) {
        setState(() {
          services.add(service);
        });
      },
      onError: (e) async {
        if (e is NsdError) {
          if (e.errorCode == NsdErrorCode.startDiscoveryFailed &&
              initialStart) {
            await stopDiscovery();
          } else if (e.errorCode == NsdErrorCode.discoveryStopped &&
              initialStart) {
            initialStart = false;
            await startDiscovery();
          }
        }
      },
    );
    startDiscovery();


  }

  Future<void> startDiscovery() async {
    if (_scanning) return;

    setState(() {
      services.clear();
      _scanning = true;
    });
    await flutterNsd.discoverServices('_http._tcp.');
    /*List<InternetAddress> addresses = await services.resolve();
    setState(() {
      _deviceIPAddresses.add(addresses[0].address);
    });*/
  }

  Future<void> stopDiscovery() async {
    if (!_scanning) return;

    setState(() {
      services.clear();
      _scanning = false;
    });
    flutterNsd.stopDiscovery();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //return MaterialApp(
      return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Your devices',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),),

          titleSpacing: 00.0,
          centerTitle: true,
          toolbarHeight: 60.2,
          toolbarOpacity: 0.6,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
          ),
          elevation: 0.00,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,


        ),

        body:
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: _buildMainWidget(context),
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                SafeArea(
                  child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: 32.0,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  tooltip: 'Add a new device',
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
                  },

                ),
                ),
                  ],
              ),


          ],
        ),
      );
   // );
  }

  Widget _buildMainWidget(BuildContext context) {
    if (services.isEmpty && _scanning) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (services.isEmpty && !_scanning) {
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    } else {
      print(services);
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.speaker,
            color: Colors.grey[500],
          ),
          title: Text(services[index].name ?? 'Invalid service name',textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 20,)
          ),
          subtitle: Text(services[index].hostname ?? 'Invalid service name',textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 10,)
          ),
          trailing: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
          ),
          onTap: ()
          {

            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              '/sixth',
              arguments:services,
            );
          },
        ),
        itemCount: services.length,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Second screen:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:australremote/screens/screen1.dart';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage6());
}



class MyHomePage6 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage6({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  _MyHomePage6State createState() => _MyHomePage6State();
}

class _MyHomePage6State extends State<MyHomePage6> {

 // final String args = "";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    //final services args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments;
    //String hostname =  args[0];
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as List<String>;

    final String services = '';
    final int index;
    final String hostname  ='';
    final String service = '';






    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Connect your DAC to your network',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87)),

        titleSpacing: 00.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        toolbarHeight: 60.2,
        toolbarOpacity: 0.6,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
        ),
        elevation: 0.00,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,


      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(service),
            //Text("Your name is :$name"),
            /*SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text("HEX value: $_hexValue"),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text("API response: $_apiResponse"),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text("SSID Hex: $_ssidHexValue"),*/
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextButton(
              onPressed:() async{

                // Send an API request with the HEX value

                var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
                    "http://10.10.10.254/httpapi.asp?command=getStatusEx"),);
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
print(response);

                 // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                } else {
                  print("There is something wrong here");

                }


              },

              child: Text("Next", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to define the getters, but I'm not quite sure I can extract the content from the arguments I've sent from the previous screen.Also, I'm receiving the following error:

*type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast*

Comment: Too many code it's confusing just for pushNamed, can you simplify the code?

Comment: You can refer the link : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: MateriApp seems missing from top level and no need to have two runApp

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:
At first screen you defined services with generic *NsdServiceInfo* like:

> `final services = <NsdServiceInfo>[];`

but on second screen , at modalRoute you used *String* as generic like:

> `final args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as List<String>;`

**Solution**:
so make *String* to *NsdServiceInfo* in route arg defining variable like:

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as List<NsdServiceInfo>;
```